# IN AndriodStudio how to apply condtions in onBindViewHolder and if they satisfy add to recylerview else how to decrease the itemCount size

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

```
public class myAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myAdapter.myViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<user_data>user_dataArrayList;
    String worker_bussiness_nam,worker_locality,worker_pnumber;

    double client_lat=0,client_lon=0,worker_lat,worker_lon,worker_km;
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    double km = 0;


    public myAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<user_data> user_dataArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.user_dataArrayList = user_dataArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myAdapter.myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_row,parent,false);
        return new myViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myAdapter.myViewHolder holder, int position) {

        do{
            //getting worker data
            user_data user_data = user_dataArrayList.get(i);
            double worker_km = user_data.getWork_Km();
            double worker_lat = user_data.getWorker_lattitude();
            double worker_lon = user_data.getWorker_longitude();
            double client_lat = client_search.user_lat;
            double client_lon = client_search.user_lon;

            String worker_name = user_data.getWorker_Name();
            String worker_des = user_data.worker_description;
            String worker_num = user_data.getWorker_phonenumber();
            double lat1 = worker_lat,lon1 = worker_lon;
            double lat2 , lon2;
            lat2 = client_lat;
            lon2 = client_lon;
            double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
            double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);

            // convert to radians
            lat1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
            lat2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);

            // apply formulae
            double a = Math.pow(Math.sin(dLat / 2), 2) +
                    Math.pow(Math.sin(dLon / 2), 2) *
                            Math.cos(lat1) *
                            Math.cos(lat2);
            double rad = 6371;
            double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
            double km =  rad * c;
            if(km<worker_km){
                count++;
                 holder.w_name.setText(user_data.getWorker_Name());
                 holder.w_desc.setText(user_data.getWorker_description());
                 Log.e("show",user_data.getWorker_Name());
                 Log.e("show",user_data.getWorker_description()+"count :"+count);
                 i++;
            }else{
                user_dataArrayList.remove(i);
                notifyItemRemoved(i);

            }

        }while (i<user_dataArrayList.size());



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return count;
    }
     public static  class myViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
           TextView w_name,w_desc;
         public myViewHolder(@NonNull  View itemView) {
             super(itemView);
             w_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.worker_name);
             w_desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.worker_desc);
         }
     }

}
```

what my condition is :
I will get lattitude and longitude from user when they open app. I will get same from worker from Firestore after gettting from firestore I will apply haverse algorithm on them then I will get distance between their both(clients and workers) and then I will get workers working_km around them from firestore. If workers_working_km less than distance between (worker amd client) I will add them to recyclerview else not.